# Find column names to insert into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to do the "insert into table" and see that we need to explicitly specify the column names. Is there a way to get this data without having to manual type it out? I am doing this on BigQuery.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an example to get the column names from a table (without incurring a cost) and build the `INSERT` list at the same time:

```
WITH EmptyReference AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
  LIMIT 0
)
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'INSERT dataset.tablename (',
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(
      REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(
        TO_JSON_STRING((SELECT AS STRUCT t.*)),
        r'"([^"]+)":'),
      ', '),
    ')')
FROM (
  SELECT AS VALUE t
  FROM EmptyReference AS t
  UNION ALL SELECT AS VALUE NULL
) AS t
```

This returns:

```
INSERT dataset.tablename (word, word_count, corpus, corpus_date)
```

> [June 2019 Update](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#june_3_2019)

Support for omitting column names in INSERT and MERGE statements is now in Beta.

When the column names are omitted, all columns in the target table are included in ascending order based on their ordinal positions

More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#omitting_column_names)

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: What part of this query actually just gets the column names?

Comment: The `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(...))` part does. You can experiment with removing parts of the query to see what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

Using [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro), Elliott's query can be rewritten as:

```
WITH ColumnNames AS (
  SELECT column_name FROM dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_schema = 'tablename'
)
SELECT CONCAT(
  'INSERT dataset.tablename (',
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT column_name FROM ColumnNames), ', '),    
  ')');
```