# Getting the column name of the table in BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I need to get the column names of the table in BigQuery database (Wherein, we have no access visually).
I am generating a CSV files containing all the data in that table I am working with. Column names of the table will be use to give the data inside the CSV a header.

Is it possible to get column name of table in big query. If yes... How?

Comment: We will need more context to answer this question.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa updated

Comment: @ArciJeiricoMalabanan What you added does not help much. You will need to write some code for this to work please show us what you have written so far or write the app and come back so we can help

Comment: @ArciJeiricoMalabanan This can help: [bigquery-query-to-find-the-column-names-of-a-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338670/bigquery-query-to-find-the-column-names-of-a-table).

Comment: Search in posted already questions/answers. I can be wrong but I do remember answering such or very similar question

Comment: Try pandas [read_gbq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_gbq.html) you will a data frame with data and column names

Comment: @FelipeHoffa to be honest, I'm still working for this one. Unfortunately, no luck at all. I am looking for the equivalent code for this "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='[database]' AND table_name='[table_name]'"

Comment: Found the answer I was looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50978615/1308883

Comment: @ArciJeiricoMalabanan information schema is under alpha, if you have a good reason subscribe to it with your project details here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906063