# Can you get column names from a Select statement in the big query SDK without running it

Tags: google-bigquery

Given a SELECT statement in Big Query and the **Java SDK**, what are my options to get the actual column names without fetching the data? I know I can execute the statement and then get the Schema via the TableResult. But is there a way to get the names without fetching data? We have a tool where we run arbitrary queries which are not known upfront and in my code I want to access the result columns by name.

**Update**: someone flagged this as duplicate of a 7 year old entry. I am however looking for a way to use the Java SDK alone to get the column names, not to do some magic with the query itself or query some metatable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bigquery query to find the column names of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338670/bigquery-query-to-find-the-column-names-of-a-table)

Answer (score 1):

There are few options but the easiest is to add `limit 0` to your query so for example:

```
SELECT * FROM projectId.datasetId.tableId limit 0
```

Comment: Or leave the query as-is and use the `dryRun` setting.

Comment: I will test `dryRun` first, because then I wouldn't have to modify the query. However, I vaguely remember that you don't have a `TableResult` in the Java SDK when doing a `dryRun` - hence no access to a `Schema`. I could be wrong. Will re-test.